# SQL Insert Statement with Null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, insert-into

Im trying to insert data into a table which has an attribute that can be Null. However, im not sure how to accomplish this with my SQL statements.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[INVOICE]
           ([INV_ID]
           ,[EMP_ID]
           ,[WAR_ID]
           ,[REP_ID]
           ,[FIN_ID]
           ,[INV_DATE]
           ,[INV_PRICE])
     VALUES
(5655,8,1**,,**3,'7/5/2000',75880),
(9749,1,1**,,**1,'11/26/2002',58881),
(9909,3,1**,187,**3,'12/27/2012',64859);
```

Comment: using NULL doesn't work? (5655,8,1**,null,**3,'7/5/2000',75880)

Comment: Yea it does, I just didn't know that was how it was done. Im really new to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[INVOICE]
           ([INV_ID]
           ,[EMP_ID]
           ,[WAR_ID]
           ,[REP_ID]
           ,[FIN_ID]
           ,[INV_DATE]
           ,[INV_PRICE])
     VALUES
(5655,8,1,NULL,3,'7/5/2000',75880),
(9749,1,1,NULL,1,'11/26/2002',58881),
(9909,3,1,NULL,3,'12/27/2012',64859);
```

You could use `NULL` to represent null

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I was explaining that he could use it anywhere in the query, as he had told that "which has an attribute that can be Null".

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[INVOICE]
           ([INV_ID]
           ,[EMP_ID]
           ,[WAR_ID]
           ,[REP_ID]
           ,[FIN_ID]
           ,[INV_DATE]
           ,[INV_PRICE])
     VALUES (5655,8,1**,NULL,**3,'7/5/2000',75880), (9749,1,1**,NULL,**1,'11/26/2002',58881), (9909,3,1**,187,**3,'12/27/2012',64859);
```

Comment: oh, its that simple eh. Thanks!